# How to compare columns from two files and print first column of first file and second column of second file and missing values NA?

Tags: awk

I have two files and trying to compare two files and printing specific values but somewhere I am missing something. Try to rectify my mistake.

File 1

```
Saureus08BA02176_01020 NA
Saureus08BA02176_02495 COG1510 K    
Saureus08BA02176_02020 COG1854 T 
Saureus08BA02176_01302 COG3763 S 
Saureus08BA02176_01834 COG0744 M 
Saureus08BA02176_01131 NA
Saureus08BA02176_02481 COG0579 R
```

File 2

```
Saureus08BA02176_01381 1.00000
Saureus08BA02176_00001 1.00000
Saureus08BA02176_01020 324.08332
Saureus08BA02176_01131 999.00000
Saureus08BA02176_02481 4.07781
```

Required output

```
Saureus08BA02176_01020 NA 324.08332
Saureus08BA02176_02495 COG1510 K NA   
Saureus08BA02176_02020 COG1854 T NA
Saureus08BA02176_01302 COG3763 S NA
Saureus08BA02176_01834 COG0744 M NA
Saureus08BA02176_01131 NA 999.000
Saureus08BA02176_02481 COG0579 R 4.07781
```

Command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0,a[$1]?a[$2]:"NA"}' file2 file1 > test1
```

It is not printing the $2 values of file 2..Where I did mistake?

Comment: please learn to use the edit tool bar at the top of the edit box, specifically the `{}` tool to format text as code/data/text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a[$1]?a[$2]:"NA"
         ^
       your array has no element, with index being second field of file1
```

You have `a[$1]?a[$2]:"NA"` atleast if there were `a[$1]?a[$1]:"NA"`, would have worked, but its not good practice better use `(index_key in array)`, so it becomes `(($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA")`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0, (($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA") }' file2 file1
```

Comment: Could you explain a little?

Answer (score 0):

If the order of records is not critical, use can simply use ***join*** approach:

```
join -a1 -e "NA" <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

The output:

```
Saureus08BA02176_01020 NA 324.08332
Saureus08BA02176_01131 NA 999.00000
Saureus08BA02176_01302 COG3763 S NA
Saureus08BA02176_01834 COG0744 M NA
Saureus08BA02176_02020 COG1854 T NA
Saureus08BA02176_02481 COG0579 R 4.07781
Saureus08BA02176_02495 COG1510 K NA
```